# Merging/Appending Justs in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative, option-type

I'm trying to do what must be blindingly obvious in Haskell, which is go from `Just [1]` and `Just [2]` to `Just [1, 2]`. However I can't find anything online as I keep finding related but unhelpful pages. So, how do you achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `liftA2 (++)`:

```
liftA2 (++) :: Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a]
```

`liftA2` just lifts a binary function into an [`Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html). `Applicative`s were designed for lifting functions of arbitrary arguments in a context, so they're perfect for this. In this case, the `Applicative` we're using is `Maybe`. To see how this works, we can look at the definition:

```
liftA2 :: (Applicative f) => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
liftA2 f a b = f <$> a <*> b
```

`(<$>)` just lifts any function on pure values to one operating inside `f`: `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. (It's just an alias for `fmap`, if you're familiar with `Functor`s.) For `Maybe`:

```
_ <$> Nothing = Nothing
f <$> Just x = Just (f x)
```

`(<*>)` is a bit trickier: it applies a function inside `f` to a value inside `f`: `f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. For `Maybe`:

```
Just f <*> Just x = Just (f x)
_ <*> _ = Nothing
```

(In fact, `f <$> x` is the same thing as `pure f <*> x`, which is `Just f <*> x` for `Maybe`.)

So, we can expand the definition of `liftA2 (++)`:

```
liftA2 (++) a b = (++) <$> a <*> b

-- expand (<$>)
liftA2 (++) (Just xs) b = Just (xs ++) <*> b
liftA2 (++) _ _ = Nothing

-- expand (<*>)
liftA2 (++) (Just xs) (Just ys) = Just (xs ++ ys)
liftA2 (++) _ _ = Nothing
```

Indeed, we can use these operators to lift a function of *any* number of arguments into any `Applicative`, just by following the pattern of `liftA2`. This is called *applicative style*, and is very common in idiomatic Haskell code. In this case, it might even be more idiomatic to use it directly by writing `(++) <$> a <*> b`, if `a` and `b` are already variables. (On the other hand, if you're partially applying it — say, to pass it to a higher-order function — then `liftA2 (++)` is preferable.)

Every `Monad` is an `Applicative`, so if you ever find yourself trying to "lift" a function into a context, `Applicative` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Awesome :) Thanks, you've saved me tearing my hair out. Don't suppose you know an equivalent for `[2]` and `Just [3]` -> `Just [2, 3]` do you? :)

Comment: @DeanBarnes: `(2 :) <$> Just [3]`

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you @ehird! This is basically my reference from now on :)

Comment: You're welcome! :) To generalise what @JoeyAdams said, `(xs ++) <$> mys` works for prepending any `xs :: [a]` inside an `mys :: Maybe [a]`.

Answer (score 3):

while @ehird's answer is great, I would have used a noobish solution in the form:

```
mergeJust a b = do
    a' <- a
    b' <- b
    return (a' ++ b')
```

Comment: +1 even noobs, equipped with simple tools, can solve this problem. You could also write the same as a monad comprehension: `[a' ++ b' | a' <- a, b' <- b]`

Answer (score 3):

To expand the solution to a list of `Just`s, you could use

```
fmap join $ sequence [Just[1],Just[2],Just[3]]
-- Just [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it was not mentioned in other solutions, I'll say it here. The simplest way to accomplish your task, in my opinion, is to use a `<>` (or `mappend`) from `Data.Monoid`.

```
import Data.Monoid

Just [1,2] <> Just [7,8] == Just [1,2,7,8]
```

However, note that this solution, unlike ehird's applicative solution, will not short-circuit on `Nothing` values.

```
Just [1,2] <> Nothing ---> Just [1,2]
--However
(++) <$> Just [1,2] <*> Nothing ---> Nothing
```

Comment: Sometimes this will be the proper behavior, sometimes not.